# Swift protocol extension with constraint won't make class to conform that protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm learning now some P.O.P (Protocol Oriented Programming) using Swift. I've created protocol with extension:

```
protocol ActivityIndicable {
    func displayActivityIndicator()
    func hideActivityIndicator()
}

extension ActivityIndicable where Self: UIViewController {
    func dispayActivityIndicator() {
        //display
    }

    func hideActivityIndicator() {
        //hide
    }
}
```

now I have some view controller, lets say MyViewController:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ActivityIndicable {
}
```

and during compilation I got warning that `MyViewController` doesn't conform to protocol `ActivityIndicable`. Can you explain why is that? It should "use" the extension constrained for `UIViewController`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple typo:

```
func dispayActivityIndicator() {
```

You dropped the "l" in "display".

But you should be getting a more specific warning:

`note: protocol requires function 'displayActivityIndicator()' with type '() -> ()'`

If you're not, that may indicate that you have some other error.

Comment: You're right, works now! I made typo because Xcode autocompletion doesn't work for protocol extension, but it is clearly my fault.